# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem - follow up question

Tags: logic

I recently rewatched the great video that Numberphile created about Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4ndIDcDSGc) and I had a follow up question of similar nature. It essentially addresses the objective truth of a statement, outside of whatever system we impose to try and prove it. So, is it true that "every true statement can be proven true in SOME system"? Or on the other hand, do there exist statements that can never be proven true no matter what system is used, aside from paradoxes.

I'm a junior studying mathematics and physics so feel free to be somewhat technical in responses :) Thanks!

Edit: let's assume that the statement isn't an axiom and can't just be made one

Comment: We can always just assume the statement as an axiom, so your question taken literally has an easy but boring answer. But there's not nothing there. This issue is subtle and just as much about philosophy as math. See for instance http://logic.harvard.edu/koellner/QAU_reprint.pdf

Comment: How about we say for the sake of this question, in the system, the statement hasn't been taken as an axiom. This is a great point though thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @Minnella In that case you need to make the question more precise - part of the issue is exactly pinning down what this should mean.

Comment: Not taking it as an axiom is not a reasonable restriction.  Instead of taking it as an axiom, take the conjunction of it with something else.  Or take a couple axioms that allow you to derive it.  As long as the statement is not self-contradictory, there is a system it is derivable in.  Also, what do you mean for a statement to be true?  You seem to think that has meaning independent of the axioms you are using.

Comment: @RossMillikan Even if it is self-contradictory there are systems that will derive it  :)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: True enough, though any system that will derive it will derive anything else, obviously.  Perhaps not what the OP had in mind. :-)

Comment: Numberphile is well-known by mathematicians to be full of junk. Best not to attempt to learn anything from there unless you want to fill your head with junk that is hard to clean out later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is it true that "every true statement can be proven true in SOME system"?

Yes, at least under intuitionistic logic or any extension of it, including classical logic:

Let $\phi$ be our statement. Let $T$ be any theory such that

\begin{align}
T &\vdash \bot && \text{$T$ is inconsistent}
\end{align}

By [explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), $T \vdash \phi$.

---

Fine, let's assume $\neg (T \vdash \bot)$. You say

> let's assume that the statement isn't an axiom and can't just be made one.

Let $T$ be any theory such that

\begin{align}
\neg (T \vdash \neg \phi) && \text{$T$ is consistent with $\phi$}
\end{align}

Let $\psi$ be any statement such that

\begin{align}
T \vdash \psi && \text{$\psi$ is a theorem of $T$} \\
\neg(\vdash \psi \leftrightarrow \phi) && \text{$\psi$ is not tautologically equivalent to $\phi$}
\end{align}

Let

$$T' = T \cup \{\psi \rightarrow \phi\}$$

be $T$ with $\psi \rightarrow \phi$ added as an axiom. By modus ponens, $T' \vdash \phi$.

Comment: I think I follow, thanks!